# How to integrate admob mediation in app build by phonegap build?

Tags: cordova, admob, flurry, inmobi

I build my first app with Phonegap Build. I also managed to show AdMob interstitial ads. But now i want to use AdMob mediation. I created account here: InMobi, Flurry and MoPub. I added them to AdMob mediation with keys etc. But they want show up in my app? What I am missing? I only use Phonegap Build, no local phonegap.

sorry on my english

Comment: Hey. Not quite sure what the problem is. Are you able to see Admob ads but unable to see InMobi and MoPub ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please share your account name  registered with InMobi. So we will contact you on the mail id

Please make sure InMobi Adapter jar + InMobi Sdk jar is present in the project + google play service lib

Here is the integration guideline link where inmobi is present

**https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/mediation-networks**

In case of any queries please write to us on

https://www.inmobi.com/support/

Thanks,
Shashank(InMobi)

Comment: Your comments are valid for an Android app, right? Not for a Phonegap app? I'm also keen to learn on how to make the Admob mediation work on Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using , must support admob mediation with the other ad networks (inMobi , Flurry ...) .